# WiX: how to expand the variable which is used in the localized string?

Tags: wix

WiX.

This is my localized `String`:

```
<String Id="SelectInstallDir_WARNING_Text">Don't select the "$(env.ProgramData)\Autodesk\ApplicationPlugins\ProxyTools.bundle\" variant if you will use AutoCAD 2012, because its bundle-autoloader don't monitor of that directory.</String>
```

I use that string here:

```
<Control Id="warning_acad2012_text" Type="Text" X="10" Y="170" Width="350" Height="60"
         Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes">
  <Text>{\DlgFont10_important}!(loc.SelectInstallDir_WARNING_Text)</Text>
</Control>
```

But I see that `$(env.ProgramData)` variable wasn't expanded.

[image]

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want the current value at install time, instead of the value from the build machine, you should Windows Installer's [formatting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368609.aspx). Specifically you should reference a directory property such as `"... [CommonAppDataFolder] ..."` or an environment variable such as `"... [%ProgramData] ..."`.